# Balancing OpenMPI Workload - Distribute Over Master and Slave Nodes

Tags: load-balancing, openmpi

Hopefully this isn't a repeat question but I'm having an issue balancing a workload on my local cluster.  This is my current MPI hostfile:

```
#The Hostfile for Open MPI
#Master Node, 'slots=2' is used because we are running an 2-core machine
localhost slots=2

#Slave nodes, 8-core machines as well
slave1-ip slots=2
slave2-ip slots=2
slave3-ip slots=2
```

When I run `mpirun -np 4 --hostfile my_hostfile program`, it will prefer to do all of the calculations on the local host first.

For example, in my nqueens code, the distribution of calculations at the end are:

```
Node 1 computed load of 1963
Node 2 computed load of 0
Node 3 computed load of 0
Node 4 computed load of 1
```

However, when I modify my hostfile so that the line `localhost slots=2` to `localhost slots=1`, all of the calculations are run on the slave nodes and I get a much more even distribution:

```
Node 1 computed load of 497
Node 2 computed load of 486
Node 3 computed load of 493
Node 4 computed load of 488
```

Is there a way to load balance on the master thread so that it will spread work over both the master and slave nodes when I have `localhost slots=2`?  Is there some sort of config file that will specify this?  I have tried the `--loadbalance` flag and that did nothing.

P.S. I followed this tutorial when setting up my cluster:
http://techtinkering.com/2009/12/02/setting-up-a-beowulf-cluster-using-open-mpi-on-linux/

Comment: This probably depends on the used `program`. Does it dynamically distribute work on the available MPI ranks? It could just mean, that the time needed to offload the work to a different rank is relatively large compared to the amount of time each load takes to compute. This could lead to a situation where the localhost repeatedly assigns itself new load, as it has already finished its previous work and never reaches higher ranks.